# Ruby/calabash: undefined method `each' for 2:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, calabash-android

I'm stuck with an error while creating some auto test in calabash. So my code is:

```
Then /^I set some site$/ do
    arr=["Google.com","Youtube.com"]
    for i in arr.length {
        touch("* id:'browserActivity_linLout_toolbar_url'")
        sleep 5
        currentSite=arr[i]
        keyboard_enter_text (currentSite)
        sleep 10
        press_enter_button
        i=i+1
        sleep 20
        }
    end
end
```

When I try to run my test I get this error:

> undefined method `each' for 2:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
>    ./features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:339:in`/^I set some site$/'
>    features/my_first.feature:6:in `Then I set some site'

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing the `for` loop with the wrong syntax. In Ruby, use:

```
for element in arr
    #...
    currentSite = element
    #...
end
```

Or better, without `for`:

```
arr.each do |element|
    #...
    currentSite = element
    #...
end
```